# JavaScript Scope of Vaadin's "AbstractJavaScriptComponent"

Tags: javascript, java, scope, vaadin

I have integrated some HTML/JS Code into my Vaadin WebApplication by creating an AbstractJavaScriptComponent. The Component almost works as intended.

How do I call the `passInfo()` method defined in the "connector.js" without having to manually click the Button defined in the innerHTML of the "chessControll.JsLabel" Component in "chessControll.js". My Goal is to pass Information, when the onChange Event of the `init()` function is called, which is located in the same file "chessControll.js", but not part of the Component.

I have already tried to create a Custom Event and then dispatch it whenever `onChange()` in the `init()` function is called, it worked as long as I didn't listen for the Event inside of my Component (chessControll.js, chessControll.JsLabel). It seems it can only be accessed in a static way.

How can I access the chessControll.JsLabel in "chessControll.js" from the `init()` function and then dispatch the button click or listen for events inside the component to achieve the same?

**connector.js:**

```
com_*myname*_*applicationName*_JsLabel = function() {

         var mycomponent = new chessControll.JsLabel(this.getElement());

         connector = this;

          this.onStateChange = function() {
            mycomponent = this.getState().boolState; 
          };

        mycomponent.click = function() {
            connector.passInfo(true);
        };
};
```

**chessControll.js:**

```
var chessControll = chessControll || {};

chessControll.JsLabel = function (element) {

    element.innerHTML =
        "<input type='button' value='Click'/>"; 

    // Getter and setter for the value property
    this.getValue = function () {
        return element.
            getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    };

    var button = element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var self = this;



    button.onclick = function () {
        self.click();
    }; 
};

var init = function() {

      var onChange = function() {
        /*Click Button defined in JsLabel Component */
    };

};$(document).ready(init);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

The architecture of Java Web Applications doesn't allow a simple communication like i did in my example. The JavaScript made a call from the Client Side to the Server Side Vaadin Component.

I integrated the whole JavaScript, including the init function, as a Component. This way i can call the method from the init function because everything is known on the Server Side.

edited chessControll.js :

```
var chessControll = chessControll || {};

chessControll.JsLabel = function (element) {

    element.innerHTML =
        "<input type='button' value='Click'/>"; 

    // Getter and setter for the value property
    this.getValue = function () {
        return element.
            getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    };

    var button = element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var self = this;


//deleted bracket here

var init = function() {

      var onChange = function() {
        self.click();
    };

};$(document).ready(init);

} //<-- that Simple
```